# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en mongodb que me regrese lo siguiente?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express

espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo 3 modelos: Cita, Usuario, Sucursal

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta como esta:

```
getCitasCliente: async ( req, res = response ) => {

  const idCliente = req.params.idCliente;
  // const idSucursal = req.params.idSucursal;

  const citas = await Cita
      .find({idCliente}, 'idCliente nombreCliente tipoCita idSucursal idAdmin')


  res.json({
    status: 'success',
    citas
  })
```

}

Esto me regresa estos resultados:

```
"status": "success",
"citas": [
    {
        "idCliente": "5ed93644e5c3f97547d3e584",
        "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
        "_id": "5ef37c3fa57fs245f01c5b36",
        "tipoCita": "sucursal",
        "idSucursal": "5ef2cc1da46fa045f01c5b31",
        "idAdmin": "5ef2c37ea46fa045f01c5b30"
    },
    {
        "idCliente": "5ed93646e5c3f97547d3e584",
        "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
        "_id": "5ef52fa0ad04ea666d13301c",
        "tipoCita": "sucursal",
        "idSucursal": "5ef24cf4e46f754236a1526a",
        "idAdmin": "5ebf0e41c2e46f17b8c1f963"
    },
    {
        "idCliente": "5ed93676e5c3f97547d3e584",
        "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
        "_id": "5ef53d1aad07la666d13301e",
        "tipoCita": "domicilio",
        "idSucursal": "5ef24cf4e19f754236a1526a",
        "idAdmin": "5ebf0e41c2e43f17b8c1f963"
    },
    {
        "idCliente": "5ed936465e5c3f97547d3e584",
        "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
        "_id": "5eff75c88434707ba223cb3a",
        "tipoCita": "sucursal",
        "idSucursal": "5ef2cc1da57fa185f01c5b31",
        "idAdmin": "5ef2c37ea57fa043f01c5b30"
    },
```

}

En mi base de datos hay varias sucursales, estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me traiga los documentos del idSucursal más repetido de mi base de datos, sabrán alguna manera de hacer esto?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El conjunto de datos que proporcionas no tiene `idSucursal` repetidos.

Para probar el siguiente bloque de código, se insertaron algunos documentos con el fin de emular una situación en la cual, se tiene una colección de documentos con `idSucursal` repetidos.

Este código devuelve la colección de documentos `idSucursal` más repetidos por `idCliente`, sin embargo, **se debe considerar un escenario en el cual, distintos `idSucursal` pueden tener el mismo número de documentos repetidos**.
Este escenario también se puede resolver, con la información que devuelve este bloque de código.

Primero, se obtiene el nombre de la base de datos:

```
const database = client.db("nombre_de_bd");
```

Después, se codifica un pipeline para *aggregation framework*.

El primer stage, va por el `idCliente`:

```
const match_stage = {$match:{idCliente: idCliente}};
```

El segundo stage, agrupa todas las sucursales que existen y regresa un conteo de las mismas:

```
const group_stage = {$group:{_id: "$idSucursal",sucursales_repetidas:{$sum: 1}}};
```

El tercer stage, ordena por las sucursales que más se repiten, a las que menos se repiten:

```
const sort_stage = {$sort:{sucursales_repetidas: -1}};
```

Y el cuarto stage, proyecta los campos que se devuelven:

```
const project_stage = {$project:{_id:"$_id",sucursales_repetidas:"$sucursales_repetidas"}};
```

Luego, se ejecuta el pipeline en *aggregation framework*, aqui se necesita el *nombre de la colección*, me parece que en el ejemplo se llama `Cita`:

```
const idSucursales_Repetidas = await database.collection("nombre_de_coleccion")
        .aggregate(queryPipeline,{ allowDiskUse: true })
        .toArray();
```

El resultado de esta operación, es un arreglo con todos los `idSucursal`, ordenado por el que más se repite:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente, se hace una consulta, se busca por el `idCliente` y además, por el `idSucursal` que más se repite, **el cual se encuentra en la primera posición del arreglo** `idSucursales_Repetidas` devuelto por *aggregation framework*:

```
const cursor = await database.collection("nombre_de_coleccion").find(
            {idCliente:idCliente,
            idSucursal:idSucursales_Repetidas[0]._id}
});
```

El bloque de código, puede quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
getCitasCliente: async ( req, res = response ) => {

    const idCliente = req.params.idCliente;
    // const idSucursal = req.params.idSucursal;
    
    //el nombre de la base de datos
    const database = client.db("nombre_bd");
    //pipeline
    const match_stage = {$match:{idCliente:idCliente}};
    const group_stage = {$group:{_id: "$idSucursal",sucursales_repetidas:{$sum: 1}}};
    const sort_stage = {$sort:{sucursales_repetidas: -1}}; 
    const project_stage = {$project:{_id:"$_id",sucursales_repetidas:"$sucursales_repetidas"}};

    const queryPipeline = [
        match_stage,
        group_stage,
        sort_stage,
        project_stage
    ];
    //verifica si el nombre de coleccion es Cita
    const idSucursales_Repetidas = await database.collection("nombre_de_coleccion")
    .aggregate(queryPipeline,{ allowDiskUse: true })
    .toArray();
    
    //console.log(idSucursales_Repetidas[0]._id);
    //console.log(idSucursales_Repetidas[0].sucursales_repetidas);
    
    const cursor = await database.collection("nombre_de_coleccion").find(
        {idCliente:idCliente,
        idSucursal:idSucursales_Repetidas[0]._id}
    );

    if ((await cursor.count()) === 0) {
        console.log("No documents found!");
    }
    
    let returnDocs = await cursor.toArray();
    
    res.json({
      status: 'success',
      returnDocs
    })
    
  }
```

No puedo asegurar que funcione, pues el conjunto de datos que proporcionas no puede replicar el resultado, use datos de prueba; la sugerencia es que lo pruebes de tu lado y nos informes de los resultados. Puede que tengas que adaptar algunas líneas del código.

En cuanto al escenario descrito arriba, en donde puede que haya documentos con el mismo número de repetidos por `idSucursal`, puedes crear las consultas y la lógica necesaria para manejar cada uno de ellos, esto con ayuda el arreglo devuelto por el *aggregation framework*, pues ya sabes que los primeros items, tienen el `idSucursal` de los documentos que más conteos registraron.

Si hay documentos `idSucursal` con el mismo número de repetidos, serán siempre los primeros items del arreglo `idSucursales_Repetidas`.

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta, muchas gracias. Me funcionó perfectamente de la siguiente manera:

Comment: const agrupados = await Cita
      .aggregate( [ 
        { $match: { 'idCliente': idCliente } },
        { $group: { _id: '$idSucursal', 'repetidos': {$sum: 1} } } 
      ] )
      .sort('-repetidos')

Comment: Esto ya me devolvió el id y el conteo de las sucursales que mas se repiten de manera descendente